# iOS release version list

Tags: ios, version, release

I am searching for a full list of all iOS released version. Does apple have a official list like that in Android? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you are looking for Steve? Do you want a list of all released iOS versions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history Or a list of all iOS APIs? http://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is going off the IPSW lists

http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/25/download-iphone-firmware-ipsw/

There is an internal Apple one, I haven't seen it in a long time and don't have the link any longer

Answer (score 0):

IPSW 3.0.0
3.0.0 (iPhone 2G): iPhone1,1_3.0_7A341_Restore.ipsw
3.0.0 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_3.0_7A341_Restore.ipsw
3.0.0 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_3.0_7A341_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 3.0.1
3.0.1 (iPhone 2G): iPhone1,1_3.0.1_7A400_Restore.ipsw
3.0.1 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_3.0.1_7A400_Restore.ipsw
3.0.1 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_3.0.1_7A400_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 3.1.0
3.1.0 (iPhone 2G): iPhone1,1_3.1_7C144_Restore.ipsw
3.1.0 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_3.1_7C144_Restore.ipsw
3.1.0 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_3.1_7C144_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 3.1.2
3.1.2 (iPhone 2G): iPhone1,1_3.1.2_7D11_Restore.ipsw
3.1.2 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_3.1.2_7D11_Restore.ipsw
3.1.2 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_3.1.2_7D11_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 3.1.3
3.1.3 (iPhone 2G): iPhone1,1_3.1.3_7E18_Restore.ipsw
3.1.3 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_3.1.3_7E18_Restore.ipsw
3.1.3 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_3.1.3_7E18_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 4.0.0
4.0.0 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_4.0_8A293_Restore.ipsw
4.0.0 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_4.0_8A293_Restore.ipsw
4.0.0 (iPhone 4): iPhone3,1_4.0_8A293_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 4.0.1
4.0.1 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_4.0.1_8A306_Restore.ipsw
4.0.1 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_4.0.1_8A306_Restore.ipsw
4.0.1 (iPhone 4): iPhone3,1_4.0.1_8A306_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 4.0.2
4.0.2 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_4.0.2_8A400_Restore.ipsw
4.0.2 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_4.0.2_8A400_Restore.ipsw
4.0.2 (iPhone 4): iPhone3,1_4.0.2_8A400_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 4.1.0
4.1.0 (iPhone 3G): iPhone1,2_4.1_8B117_Restore.ipsw
4.1.0 (iPhone 3GS): iPhone2,1_4.1_8B117_Restore.ipsw
4.1.0 (iPhone 4): iPhone3,1_4.1_8B117_Restore.ipsw
IPSW 4.2.1
iOS 4.2 was released as iOS 4.2.1 and this IPSW reflects that:

iPhone 4
iPhone 3GS
iPhone 3G
IPSW 4.2.6
iOS 4.2.6 IPSW is thus far only intended for CDMA iPhone 4 models:

CDMA iPhone 4
IPSW 4.3
iOS 4.3 supports iPhone 4 and iPhone 3GS:

iPhone 4 (GSM)
iPhone 3GS
IPSW 4.3.1
iPhone 3GS
iPhone 4 GSM
iPhone IPSW for iOS 4.3.3
iPhone 3GS
iPhone 4 GSM
iPhone 4 CDMA – iOS 4.2.8
iPhone IPSW for iOS 4.3.4
iPhone 4 (GSM)
iPhone 4 (CDMA) (iOS 4.2.9)
iPhone 3GS
iOS 4.3.5 IPSW for iPhone
iPhone 4 GSM
iPhone 4 CDMA (iOS 4.2.10)
iPhone 3GS
iOS 5 IPSW
iPhone 3GS
iPhone 4 GSM
iPhone 4 CDMA
iOS 5.0.1 IPSW
iPhone 4S
iPhone 4 GSM
iPhone 4 CDMA
iPhone 3GS
iOS 5.0.1 9A406 IPSW
iPhone 4S 9A406
iOS 5.1 IPSW
iPhone 3GS
iPhone 4 GSM (AT&T)
iPhone 4 CDMA (Verizon)
iPhone 4S
iOS 5.1.1 IPSW
iPhone 3GS
iPhone 4 GSM
iPhone 4 CDMA
iPhone 4S